# Is there a standard way to reference the same object between classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, object, outlook

When I search this question, all of the answers I've seen only talk about handling an object within the same class but I need to handle the same data between classes.

I'm building an outlook addin which uses three classes to make up the key components of my programme:
**ThisAddin** - the default class created with the MS VS template, I'm using this class to store all of my methods, enums, data stores etc..
**Ribbon** - my outlook Ribbon containing a button to initiate a new enquiry form. Within the button_click is also a code to save relevant attachments from a selected email to a specified filepath.
**NewEntry** - a winform dialogue initiated when the ribbon button is clicked, used to create new enquiries.

I also have a class called **NewSearchQuery** which I was hoping to use as a datastore for all the relevant aspects of a new enquiry.

current logic goes like this - user presses button in the ribbon, a new object (referenced as Temp) is called and known data for some parameters are filled. Winform is opened and user fills in some more required data. On form submit, that data is added to the object metadata, a reference number is generated from a database, a file path is created using the reference number and all this is again added to the object metadata. Winform dialog closes and the ribbon saves the selected email attachments to the specified filepath stored within the object. Now all the object metadata can be sent to the enquiry database as a new enquiry.

Here's the code:

```
public enum ContractType
{
    Searches, //there are other values in my code but they don't need to feature here
}

public class NewSearchQuery
{
    public string Name, Location, SearchType, Path;
    public int RefNum;
    public bool Paid;
    public ContractType Contract;
}

public partial class Ribbon
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        NewSearchQuery Temp = new NewSearchQuery();
        Temp.Contract = ContractType.Searches;
        var NewEntry = new NewEntry(Convert.ToString(Temp.Contract));
        NewEntry.ShowDialog();

        //wait until the NewEntry Dialogue and associated methods close and then run the below save attachments method:

        var m = e.Control.Context as Inspector;
        var mailitem = m.CurrentItem as MailItem;
        mailitem.SaveAs(Temp.Path + @"\Initial_Contact.msg");
        if (mailitem != null)
        {
            if (mailitem.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Attachment item in mailitem.Attachments)
                {
                    string[] extensionsArray = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".tiff", ".tif", ".eps", ".bmp", ".vcf" };
                    if (!extensionsArray.Any(item.FileName.Contains))
                    {
                        item.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(Temp.Path, item.FileName));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Operation Complete. Enquiry number {Temp.RefNum}. This email doesn't have any attachments.");
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show($"Operation Complete, Enquiry number {Temp.RefNum}.");
    }
}
public partial class NewEntry : Form
{
    public NewEntry(string ContractType)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here are the variables I would like to tie into the Temp object created in Ribbon
        Temp.Name = Convert.ToString(Companies.SelectedItem);
        Temp.Location = Convert.ToString(SearchLocation.Text);
        Temp.SearchType = Convert.ToString(Search.SelectedItem);
        Temp.Paid = Paid.Checked;

        if (Temp.Name == "" || Location == "" || SearchType == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure you have filled in all the required fields (*) before proceeding", "ERROR: insufficient info");
        }
        else
        {

            Temp.RefNum = ThisAddIn.FindIdNum();
            Temp.Path = ThisAddIn.CreateFilePath(Temp.RefNum);
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(d));
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reference the same object from both the Ribbon and NewEntry classes to keep all my required data centralised?

Comment: Encapsulate the logic in an interface (e.g. ISearchQueryService) and pass an instance of that interface to both the classes that want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need to actually share and you only want NewEntry to give you a NewSearchQuery when it completes.

That is pretty easy just add a method on NewEntry like this:

```
public NewSearchQuery GetEntry()
{
    // make a new NewSearchQuery
    var q = new NewSearchQuery();
    // set its values from the form eg 
    q.Name = Convert.ToString(Companies.SelectedItem);
    return q;
}
```

Then in the ribbon just do this after the ShowDialog:

```
var q = NewEntry.GetEntry();
```

So the idea is that the NewSearchQuery is always created by the form.

If you want a 2 way thing, create the NewSearchQuery first, then pass to the form using a similar method that initializes the form from the values.